# Unable to set cursor position in virtualbox

Tags: c#

I have a dev machine in virtualbox. In this machine I try to set the position of the cursor. But it doesn't move.

My code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
public static void SetCursorPosition(int X, int Y)
{
    bool res=SetCursorPos(X, Y);//this function doesn't move cursor
    //In VM res=true;
}
```

This code only works outside of the VM.

Comment: Did you checked the return of `SetCursorPos` ?

Comment: What is X, and Y? Are the points on-screen? It is possible that VB filters mouse move out?

Comment: X and Y it's coordinate of mouse. I setup X=100, Y=100. In real PC it's move, but on VM it's doesn't move.

Comment: And is the flag `WINSTA_WRITEATTRIBUTES` set properly?

Comment: No. I don't see this flag in my code.

Comment: many VMs fake the cursor display.  Its possible that you *are* moving the cursor but the guest OS has its cursor set to hidden so the VM host can do some kind of host/guest integration.